# Azure multiple apps with react, unable to access other apps after loading react in broswer

Tags: reactjs, azure

I have multiple apps running in the same domain in Azure.
I added react project last week.
We have back office app separately running built using asp.net MVC.
we have react project now.  When I load the react in the browser it works correctly. 
let's say xxx.azurewesites.net/ will load react by default and xx.azurewebsites.net/backoffice/login.axpx will load another app.
If I type the URL to access the back office app the problem comes in, now react scripts in the browser cache picks up the URL and try to match with react router and loads no route match page. I'm unable to load the back-office app anymore if I hard reload the page it loads the BO App now. how can we handle this problem I want to access the BO App even the react is loaded in the browser. How to prevent the react from getting the URL. I want to skip react router and send the request to the server so that server will send the BO App page.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question, but could you not just use an anchor tag `<a href="xxx.azurewebsites.net/backoffice/login.axpx"> External page </a>` instead of `Link` if you want to leave the React app?

Comment: I tried that it's not working when I do that again react picks the URL and tries to load the same react app. is there any configuration can be done on the server I setup the server to serve to react by default you think that might cause the problem? I have set the routing to point the index.html by default. I'm just entering the URL directly to the browser URL bar still I get the react app picking up the URL